# Spoj-Prime Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, primes

**Question-**

Generate all prime numbers between two given numbers.

https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

**My attempt-**

I used segmented sieve method.

```
t=int(input())
import math
def segsieve(x):
    if x==1:
        return False
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(x))+1):
        if x%i==0:
            return False
    return True

while t>0:
    f,l=map(int,input().split())
    for j in range(f,l):
        a=segsieve(j)
        if a==True:
            print(j)
    t-=1
```

**Issue-**

I am getting time limit exceeded. How can I make it faster?

Comment: You never decrement `t`, so your code runs an infinite loop, exceeding any time limit.

Comment: One important rule on Code Review is not to change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). – In this particular case however it might be tolerated, since the problem of the missing decrement of `t` (causing an infinite loop) was not addressed in the answer at all.

Answer (score 2):

## Algorithm

### Hint

You don't need to check all integers between `2` and `int(math.sqrt(x))+1`. You only need to check primes between `2` and `int(math.sqrt(x))+1`.

## Stylistic

### `__main__`

I would add a "main function" to your program. This is typically done in Python by:

```
def main():
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/667648) for more reasons why this paradigm is followed.

### `sqrt`

I technically have not measured the performance of `sqrt`, but I have more commonly seen your `for` loop written as:

```
while i * i < x:
    ...
```

unlike the current:

```
for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(x))+1):
```

No need to `import math` then.

### PEP 8

According to the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide, you should add a space between the mathematical operations. So for instance, instead of:

```
if x%i==0:
```

it should be:

```
if x % i == 0:
```

Comment: In your hint it says basically: You don't need to do `A`, do `A` instead?

Comment: Umm your hint is saying what I have already done.

Comment: @suyashsingh234 I may have miswrote, but do you check only primes between 2 and sqrt(x)? It looks like you check all integers.

Comment: @Graipher See the comment. I forgot the word "all integers" in the first qualifier.